# Get shadowed members of variadic template with recursive inheritance by type

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++14, variadic-templates

I have something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    typedef T Type;
};

template <typename...> class B;

template <typename TFirst, typename... TRest>
class B<TFirst, TRest...> : public B<TRest...> {
public:
    typedef typename TFirst::Type Type;

    TFirst a;

    virtual void func(TFirst a, Type t) = 0;
};

template <>
class B<> {};

struct X {};
struct Y {};

class ASub1 : public A<X> {};
class ASub2 : public A<Y> {};

class BSub : public B<ASub1, ASub2> {
public:
    // Implement all pure virtual methods
    // void func(ASub1 a1, Type t) override {}
    // void func(ASub2 a2, Type t) override {}
};
```

Now I have two questions:

1. How would I be able to implement all pure virtual methods in `BSub`? I somehow need to access the template arguments (types) of all `ASubX`.
2. Is there a way to access all the members `a` by passing the `ASubX`? I mean something like `get<ASub1>(b_sub)` if `b_sub` were an instance of `BSub`.

I would prefer a solution with C++14.

Comment: As for 2. `b_sub.B<ASub1, ASub2>::a` should do the trick. Have in mind you can have several `ASubX` passed to `B`, compiler need to know specifically to which one you are referring to...

Answer (score 2):

For (1), you can write

```
class BSub : public B<ASub1, ASub2> {
public:
    void func (ASub1, typename ASub1::Type) override {}
    void func (ASub2, typename ASub2::Type) override {}
};
```

or, remebering that `ASub1::Type` is `X` and `ASub2::Type` is `Y`,

```
class BSub : public B<ASub1, ASub2> {
public:
    void func (ASub1, X) override {}
    void func (ASub2, Y) override {}
};
```

For (2), as suggested by W.F., you can use

```
b_sub.B<ASub1, ASub2>::a
```

to access the `ASub1` component and

```
b_sub.B<ASub2>::a
```

to access the `ASub2` one.

The following is a full working (simplified) example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct A
 { using Type = T; };

template <typename...>
struct B;

template <typename TFirst, typename ... TRest>
struct B<TFirst, TRest...> : public B<TRest...>
 {
    using Type = typename TFirst::Type;

    TFirst a;

    virtual void func (TFirst a, Type t) = 0;
 };

template <>
struct B<> {};

struct X {};
struct Y {};

struct ASub1 : public A<X> {};
struct ASub2 : public A<Y> {};

struct BSub : public B<ASub1, ASub2>
 {
   void func (ASub1, X) override { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
   void func (ASub2, Y) override { std::cout << 2 << std::endl; }
 };

int main()
 {
   BSub bs;

   bs.func(ASub1{}, X{});
   bs.func(ASub2{}, Y{});

   using T1 = decltype(bs.B<ASub1, ASub2>::a);
   using T2 = decltype(bs.B<ASub2>::a);

   static_assert(std::is_same<T1, ASub1>{}, "!");
   static_assert(std::is_same<T2, ASub2>{}, "!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by an implementation of `std::get` for `std::tuple` I came up with following solution.

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    using Type = T;
};

template <typename...> class B;

template <typename TFirst, typename... TRest>
class B<TFirst, TRest...> : public B<TRest...> {
public:
    using AType = typename TFirst::Type;
    using Type = B<TFirst, TRest...>;

    TFirst a;

    virtual void func(TFirst a, AType t) {}
};

template <>
class B<> {};

struct X {};
struct Y {};

class ASub1 : public A<X> { public: int value = 10; };
class ASub2 : public A<Y> { public: int value = 20; };

class BSub : public B<ASub1, ASub2> {
public:
    // Implement all pure virtual methods
    void func(ASub1 a1, typename ASub1::Type t) {}
    void func(ASub2 a2, typename ASub2::Type t) {}
};

template <typename TA, typename TB> class BElement;

template <typename TA, typename TAFirst, typename... TARest>
class BElement<TA, B<TAFirst, TARest...>> : public BElement<TA, B<TARest...>> {
public:
};

template <typename TA, typename... TARest>
class BElement<TA, B<TA, TARest...>> {
public:
    using AType = TA;
    using BType = B<TA, TARest...>;
};

template <typename TA, typename... TAs>
TA& get(B<TAs...> & b) {
    using BType = typename BElement<TA, B<TAs...>>::BType;
    return static_cast<BType &>(b).a;
}

template <typename TA, typename TB>
TA& get(TB b) {
    return get<TA>(static_cast<typename TB::Type &>(b));
}

int main() {
  BSub bsub;
  printf("%d\n", get<ASub1>(bsub).value);
  printf("%d\n", get<ASub2>(bsub).value);

  return 0;
}
```